# What is the return type of a method that returns Heredoc?

Tags: php, php-7, heredoc, phpstan

I have some PHP code that looks like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public static function classPhpdoc($paramA)
    {
        return <<<PHP
/** @template-extends \\$baseClass */

PHP;
    }
}
```

It's basically a class with multiple methods that return Heredoc blocks.

I'm using phpstan tool to validate the code and it's complaining that the methods have no return-type specified.

My question is: what return type would be appropiate to specify in such cases? I was thinking either `string` or `mixed` but I'm not sure.

Comment: It's just a way of writing a string so... string... This should also be super easy to test yourself. Just check what the response is with either `var_dump()` or `gettype()`.

Comment: Obviously: string

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 1):

Heredoc is not a type, it's a syntax to produce strings:

```
var_dump(<<<PHP
Hello, World!
PHP
);
```

```
string(13) "Hello, World!"
```

So:

```
public static function classPhpdoc($paramA): string
```